# How to install OpenCV via Anaconda on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, anaconda

I'm trying to install OpenCV via anaconda, using the following comand:

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

And according to this tutorial I'm reading, this should be the result (it's in the image link bellow):

[``````](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT39U.png)

**However, what I am getting is this:**

```
(base) C:\Users\reisdopinhal>conda install -c conda-forge opencv
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source
```

I've had some trouble properly uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda, since last year I erased it's file instead of uninstalling it the tradicional way. I might've broken some paths and stuff :/

Can someone tell me what might be happening, and if it has something to do with it?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Don't install the package to your base environment! _I've had some trouble properly uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda, since last year I erased it's file instead of uninstalling it the tradicional way. I might've broken some paths and stuff :/_ That seems to be a reasonably common issue, unfortunately.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I actually ended up using a pip command and it worked fine thankfully

Comment: What pip command? Be careful about combining pip and Conda.

Comment: I think I used `pip install opencv-python`, however I'm not being able to find the site where I looked it up :/. But what issues might this bring? I also cannot recall wether I installed it via cmd, or the ananconda prompt

Comment: _But what issues might this bring?_ Anaconda Inc. has some information on the subject [here](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/). If there’s no obvious reason why you can’t use Conda/must use pip, you’re easily better off by just creating a new environment and getting OpenCV through Conda. It’s [available on conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv), for example.

Answer (score 0):

I usually face many problems when using conda. Using pip to install opencv works like a charm. Just run belowe code in your terminal or command prompt and then everything works fine:

```
pip install opencv-python
```